# Row_Number not avaiable in where but in order clause

Tags: sql-server, row-number

I am trying to use Row_Number, it works fine in the order by clause, but when using it in the where clause, i get invalid column, that dosnt make sense to me?

Anybody that can explain why that is? Thanks a bunch

```
SELECT col1,col2,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col2) as rownr
FROM  table1 t1 WITH(NOLOCK) 
JOIN table2 t2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE rownr > 1
ORDER BY rownr,unit
```

Answer (score 3):

Logical `processing` of `order by` is after the `select` but `where` clause is processed before `select` thats why you get that error.

To do that you should make the query as `sub-select` and filter the records in outer query

```
SELECT col1,
       col2
FROM  (SELECT col1,
              col2,
              Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col2) AS rownr,
              unit
       FROM   table1 t1 WITH(NOLOCK)
              JOIN table2 t2 WITH(NOLOCK)
                ON t2.id = t1.id) a
WHERE  rownr > 1
ORDER  BY rownr, unit
```

check here for more info on [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)

Comment: To make this more readable, you can put subquery in a CTE. :)

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas - yeah agreed but I will go for `CTE` only when my `sub-select` has to be referred more than once

Comment: Since you're already talking about it, maybe make a link to the [logical processing order of the SELECT statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) (unfortunately, we can only link to the top of that document but scrolling down finds it)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Updated :) Hope OP finds the content under the topic **Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement** in that link

Answer (score 2):

`ROW_NUMBER()` cannot be used with same query. Make `ORDER BY` in outer query.

**EDIT : You cannot use `rownr` in the same query since you are computing ROW_NUMBER() in one place. You can access `rownr` in an outer query.**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT col1,col2,unit,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col2) as rownr
   FROM  table1 t1 WITH(NOLOCK) 
   JOIN table2 t2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON t2.id = t1.id       
)TAB
WHERE rownr > 1
ORDER BY rownr,unit
```

Comment: Use cannot use rownr in the same query since you are computing ROW_NUMBER() in one place. You can access rownr in an outer query. @user2199192